# Unable to start debugging in VS2015 for Azure web app

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I'm using VS2015 Update 1 to try and debug my site which I've uploaded in Debug mode to an Azure web app (NOT a vm). I am working from my work domain.

I've been following instructions similar to found here https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/02/27/another-cool-way-to-remotely-debug-azure-web-sites/

I have:

- Published my website in Debug configuration
- Enabled Remote Debugging from the management console
- Made sure my VS edition is set to 2015
- Enabled Websockets (from trying to connect via websockets)
- Checked that the firewall allows VS remote debugger, remote debugger monitor and remote debugger discovery through.
- Checked the website is up and running (set it to always on just in case)

I have tried right clicking my app service in Server Explorer and "Attach Debugger".

I then tried to connect using Debug > Attach to process and using the qualifier mysite.azurewebsites.net as instructed on various blogs. Even tried transport as Websocket, Remote as well as Default.

All methods get me the following:
[image: Error message]

I then used Fiddler to see if I could find the answer from web traffic but no joy with that.

Would appreciate any suggestions to get me around this problem!

**Edit**
Under scm -

[image: SCM shows process]

Comment: did you check if an antivirus or related its blocking the local connection to the debug serivice? 
other setting i think can help its to activate the diagnostics log and then check the logs

Comment: Try going to https://{yoursite}.scm.azurewebsites.net/, and click on Process Exporer. Do you see `msvcmon.exe` running in there (as a child of w3wp)?

Comment: @DavidEbbo it's there (twice), updating post to add picture

Comment: @MarianoMontañezUreta AV is Windows Defender, which according to the documentation in VS allows it through

Comment: In case it comes up I'm also running 2.8.1 SDK

Comment: Also turned off AV and it still doesn't connect

Comment: Can you share your site name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? This will help us investigate. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidEbbo so it turns out there was another firewall that I wasn't aware of that was blocking the debugger leaving the network. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was another firewall I wasn't aware of on the domain that was blocking the debugger.

**Edit:**

Ports requested
outbound:

- UDP 3702
- TCP 4020
- TCP 4021

[Port assignments are given here on MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt592018.aspx)

Comment: Hello @IIessa, may I know which port or settings that one needs to open as am having a similar problem and my IT is asking me which one specifically. Any Ideas?