# Remote Debugging of Azure Web Application

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm currently using visual studio 2017 and trying to attach the debugger to my web app. I've deployed my app and i've attached the debugger through VS. I've also ensure on the azure portal that remote debugger is turned on. I've also went to https://xxxxxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/ and checked the processes and `w3wp` is available. From [Unable to start debugging in VS2015 for Azure web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727314/unable-to-start-debugging-in-vs2015-for-azure-web-app) and [Remote Debugging - Web App Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44977008/remote-debugging-web-app-azure) it indicated to me it could be a port being blocked. so i went ahead and set my firewall outbound to allow the connections from  `UDP 3702` `TCP 4020` `TCP 4021` and ports 4022 and the problem still persist. I'm unable to connect to my connection target.

I've tried `xxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net:4022` and `xxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net`

[image]

I'm all out of ideas and suggestions from the web. If anyone else has tips, that'll be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> unable to connect to my connection target.

Please refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/configure-the-windows-firewall-for-remote-debugging) to configure the firewall to enable remote debugging for VS 2017.

[image]

Remote debugging works for me using VS 2017 with following steps:

**Turn on Remote debugging and choose VS 2017**

[image]

**Find and attach to process**

[image]

Please try to enter `{your_web_app_name}.azurewebsites.net:4022` and click **Refresh** button to check if you can see available processes.

Besides, you can right-click your web app, and then click **Attach Debugger** to [remote debug the web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug) in **Server Explorer**.

[image]

**Updates:**

*Get publish profile on portal*

[image]

Comment: Hi, i've done every step you suggested but i'm stuck at the refresh part. It ask for my credentials, i've entered my azure credentials and it says authentication failed. Is there another set of credentials to use maybe that's configured through azure portal?

Comment: ``Is there another set of credentials to use maybe that's configured through azure portal?`` Please check my update and get publish profile on Azure portal.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! this has been driving me insane.